# Facebook connect API for iPhone: Logout - Login problem

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I have a problem with FaceBooks API.
I can login and logout with no problem. But when i logout and then try to login back it logs me in automatically without even asking to enter username and password. But when i logout again it works fine. It will show me back the username and password fields.

I think it has something to do with the cookies. But while debugging i found that facebook IS clearing the cookies. So i dont know where is the problem.

Thanx for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[FBSession setSession:nil];`

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. I implemented as you said. It makes sense and seems to be working fine now. But i am doing more testing on it.

Comment: Do you by chance know about any crash while uploading photos?? I traced the crashed and it always crashes in FBRequet.m at [_dataParam isKindOfClass:]. It says dealloc object was called. Any idea??

Comment: Something is being called that's been released. Can you post output from Xcode or more code?

Comment: it comes to this function in FBRequest                             - (void)connect {
  FBLOG(@"Connecting to %@ %@", _url, _params);

  if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestLoading:)]) {
    [_delegate requestLoading:self];
  }                                                                    and this is the error                                               -[NSConcreteMutableData isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6286db0

Answer (score 0):

I got the same when I used [FBRequest requestForMe] in an active (as I think) session.
I had to add

```
[FBSession.activeSession close];
```

before [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:...]
Now it works fine.